# How to increase the line width when hovering the cursor in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2, chart.js3, chart.jsv3

I know that I can change the width of the line and its points with `borderWidth: 1, pointRadius: 1`, it works fine.

But how to increase the width of the line and its points when hovering the mouse cursor over a line?
I tried `hoverBorderWidth: 2, hoverRadius: 2` as suggested in the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html) but with no success.

I tested in Google Apps Script by adding these lines to the html file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-autocolors"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right, but you are forgetting to add Chart.js datalables plugin which is essential for using hoverBorderWidth or hoverRadius.

Include

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide me the code you have used so that I could clarify you with the problem i.e. in configuration or in way you are using it

Comment: Please add the code you have that works to your answer or remove it.

Comment: I've added please to give it a close look 